# Nestjs - compilation, cannot find module dist\main

Tags: typescript, nestjs

Since I created a Library and added to the tsconfig file this way:

```
"paths": {
  "@app/common": [
    "../../libs/common/src"
  ],
  "@app/common/*": [
    "../../libs/common/src/*"
  ]
}
```

The typescript transpilation is creating two folders:

```
dist
    │
    └───apps
    │   
    └───libs
```

and returning this error: Error: Cannot find module '/Users/myName/Dev/vision/apps/users/dist/main'

How may I solve it ?

Comment: check your project entry point specified in `entryFile` in nest-cli.json, and check if there is any `main.js` in your dist/apps/your-app, if your entry file is index.js then update the `entryFile` accordingly